# Create Sql server replication with some data transformation (during or at the end)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, replication

i'm running a sql server replication to sync a table to a separate (reporting) database.

In the source database, all records have a `DateTime` value (not so unusual) but it isn't stored as a `DateTime`, but as a `Guid`... which points to a table which contains all timestamps (one for every minute).

Now what i would like to do is during the replication process (or at the end, or continuous at the target database) is lookup the timestamp (in `datetime` value) in the TimeStamps database and fill an extra field in the target database with that `DateTime` value.

The reason for that is that i can query the target database on specific datetimes without having to join it to the timestamps database.

Is this possible?

I've seen as a property of the replication a 'DTS' property, which makes me think i can somehow specify a DTS package, but the property isn't enabled and i thought DTS is deprecated?

Comment: Which replication model are you using? Transactional, Snapshot or Merge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming a transactional replication, I would customize the `sp_MSins_YourTable` and `sp_MSupd_YourTable` stored procedures on the subscriber to do the extra lookup/translation. Just be sure to fully document this customization as any time you would have to drop/recreate replication your custom procs will be replaced with the standard ones again.

Comment: Thanks, that was the place i was looking too. (and indeed found that reinitializing the replication does recreate the sp's)

Comment: this provided a good way to start. Because triggers don't get deleted when the replication restarts, i've decided to implement it in a trigger.